# How to format data for display using an ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, formatting, itemssource

I'm pretty new to WPF, so pardon my ignorance.  I currently have a List of objects that I am using as an `ItemsSource` for a `DataGrid`.  One of the fields of the objects is a float data type, and of course displays decimal places on the `DataGrid` when used as an `ItemsSource`.

I would like to remove these decimal places, without changing the underlying data, if that's possible.  In other words, I would like to display them as if they were ints on the `DataGrid`, but leave them as floats in the `List`.

If this is possible using C#, that would be super-great-nifty.  XAML makes me want to vomit :)

Comment: `XAML makes me want to vomit` - Then go back to winforms. WPF is not for newbies =)

Comment: So you prefer coding in a big long string (tag) as opposed to nice clean-cut object notation?  To each their own I suppose :)

Comment: XAML is not coding. XAML is to define the UI. and of course I prefer XAML to the multiple horrible hacks you need to do anything in other technologies (P/Invoke? Owner Draw? WTF is that??)

Comment: Semantics won't save you from the fact that tags are ugly!

Comment: again, if you don't like it, go back to your winforms' drag and drop + horrible hack stuff. Nobody forces you to WPF. You can keep making applications that look like windows 95 if you want.

Comment: By the way, I don't need to be "saved" from anything. I'm not the one arguing in favor of a dinosaur, dead and completely useless technology and mentality.

Comment: I never argued for winforms bro, just saying tags are ugly

Comment: Agreed. It would be fantastic if XAML was some form of JSON instead, still 12390812038347297 times better than anything else current in existence.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply trying to format the value for display purposes, you can use the `StringFormat` property of the `Binding` like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="My Number" Binding="{Binding MyNumber, StringFormat=N}"/>
```

This prevents the need for a `Converter` in very simple cases.  If you need more power/flexibility, then a `Converter` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: +1. Again, I'm too lazy to answer this myself. I prefer ranting in comments.

Comment: I hear ya.  It is Friday, after all.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the C# side?  I'm not currently using the binding string, but assigning 'MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = List'

Comment: @Tevis [How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx).